# iOS Google Drive SDK - Query string for folders doesn't appear to be working

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Per GTLQueryDrive.h method documentation:

```
// Method: drive.files.list
// Lists the user's files.
//  Optional:
//   q: Query string for searching files.
// Fetches a GTLDriveFileList.
+ (id)queryForFilesList;
```

Also here: https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters 
Second item under the Examples heading:

```
Search for folders using the folder-specific MIME type
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

When I perform a `queryForFilesList` and set `q`, I get a non-error result but the contents of the GTLFileList only has two properties set, `kind` and `etag`. There is nothing else returned in the results.  See below:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];

query.q = @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";

[self.fileChecker executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        //I see this in the console...
        //No Errors in Folder Query: 
        //GTLDriveFileList 0x108f3430: {kind:"drive#fileList" 
        //etag:""Q5ElJByAJoL0etObruYVPRipH1k/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8""}
        NSLog(@"No Errors in Folder Query: %@",object);

        GTLDriveFileList *list = (GTLDriveFileList *)object;

        //So, none of this for() loop happens
        for (GTLDriveFile *file in list.items) {
            NSLog(@"Folder: \n \n %@ \n \n",file);  
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Folder Query Error: %@",error);
    }
}];
```

Anything I'm doing wrong? The iOS Google Drive app can definitely find a list of Folders. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My code is correct. I was using the wrong permissions when accessing Google Drive. I changed it from `kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile` (which only shows you files and folders you created with your app) to `kGTLAuthSchopeDrive` (which will show you content created on the site and other apps)

You use this constant when signing in to Google Drive and presenting the `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` xib file.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this question, the solution for my query problem was using:

```
let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
query.q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

instead of :

```
let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
query.mimeType = "'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```